# How to make a secure paypal checkout payment with php

Tags: php, security, paypal, checkout, express-checkout

I have a little PayPal code to implement payments with the checkout button.
This button shows a pop-up window with the options to pay (with account or credit/debit card)

The problem is that I pass the value of the things I'm selling with hidden input texts of HTML.

So, everyone can edit this quantity

```
   <tr style="visibility: hidden;">
                <td><!--Quantity:--></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0" value="1" readonly style="display: none"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="visibility: hidden;">
                <td><!--Price:--></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT" value="<?=$money?>" readonly style="display: none"></input></td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="visibility: hidden;">
                <td><!--Total Amount:--></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="<?=$money?>" readonly style="visibility: hidden;"></input></td>
            </tr>
```

if somebody wants to edit the value of  PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT, he could pay whatever he wants.

I call the checkout button like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
        paypal.checkout.setup('<?php echo($merchantID); ?>', {
            container: 'myContainer',
            addres_override :'true',
            showShippingAddress:'false',
            environment: '<?php echo($env); ?>'
        });
    };
</script>
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

So, I would like to pass the parameters of value through PHP or something not editable.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: use `<input type="hidden" .. readonly>`

Comment: @marcusshep no, not good enough. You can manipulate the values with inspect element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just have the submit button submit to a PHP script that actually runs the Express Checkout API call. Such as:

```html
<form id="myContainer" method="post" action="/checkout.php"></form>
```

And the PHP at checkout.php just runs the script. Save the price and other info as session variables so they're not editable.